# AngularJs [$injector:unpr] error

Tags: angularjs, razor

I got a error when inject ngHandsOnTable in my controller ,

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=ngHandsontableProvider%20%3C-%20ngHandsontable%20%3C-%20StokesTypeListController

`Index.cshtml`, I have used:

```
<link href="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/Styles/handsontable.full.css?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------lib------------------------------------------------------>

<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/lib/jquery-2.1.1.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>
<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/Lib/jquery-ui-1.12.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>
<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/Lib/angular.min.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>
<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/Lib/handsontable/handsontable.full.min.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>
<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/Lib/angular-sanitize.min.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>
<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/Lib/angualr-ui-router.min.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>
<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/Lib/angular-cookies.min.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>
@*<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/Lib/handsontable/pikaday.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>
<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/Lib/handsontable/ZeroClipboard.min.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>*@
<script src="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/App/Lib/handsontable/ngHandsontable.min.js?version=@ViewBag.AppVersion"></script>
```

Here is `Controller.JS`:

```
stokestypeListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$state', '$window', 'dataContext', 'ngHandsontable'] //inject dependecies required

module.controller(controllerId, stokestypeListController) // assiging controller to the module

//contstructor
function stokestypeListController($scope, $location, $state, $window, dataContext, ngHandsontable) {
```

Comment: did you inject this to module

Comment: Yaa, When I inject this module , then i got this error

Comment: Formatting changes for readability

Comment: Where are you registering `ngHandsontable` in the module?